# Why is readLine() resulting in undefined error with InputStreamReader?

Tags: java, inputstream

I am creating a simple IRC client in Java. I am running into a problem when attempting to read a data stream from the server using InputStreamReader wrapped in BufferedReader. Examples I have found all use the readLine() method to capture the data. However, I am receiving the following error, when I use this approach:

> readLine() is undefined for the type InputStreamReader

The error first appears in my `while` loop. Here is the code:

```
public class IRCClient {

    //Initialize the input and output streams
    private Socket socket               = null;
    private InputStreamReader reader    = null; //What we receive from the host
    private OutputStreamWriter writer   = null; //What we send to the host

        //Client constructor
    public IRCClient(String address, int port, String nick, String login, String channel) {

        //Establish a connection to the host
        try
        {
            socket = new Socket(address, port);

            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        }
        catch(UnknownHostException u)
        {
            System.out.println(u);
        }
        catch(IOException i)
        {
            System.out.println(i);
        }

        //Login to the host
        try
        {
            writer.write("NICK " + nick + "\r\n");
            writer.write("USER " + login + "\r\n");
            writer.flush();
        }
        catch(IOException i)
        {
            System.out.println(i);
        }

        //Read lines from the server to make sure we are connected
        String line = null;
        try
        {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                if (line.indexOf("004") >= 0) {
                    // We are logged in
                    break;
                } else if (line.indexOf("433") >= 0) {
                    System.out.println("Nickname is already in use");
                    return;
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException i) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }

        // Join the specified channel
        writer.write("JOIN " + channel + "\r\n");
        writer.flush();

        // Keep reading lines from the host.
        while ((line = reader.read()) != null) {
            if (line.toLowerCase().startsWith("PING ")) {
                //Respond with PONG tro avoid being disconnected
                writer.write("PONG " + line.substring(5) + "\r\n");
                writer.flush();
            }
            else {
                //Print the line received
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        } //end while
    }

    //Instantiate the client object
    public static void main(String[] args){

        //Connection details
        String serverAddress    = "irc.chat.twitch.tv";
        int serverPort      = 6667;
        String nick         = args[0];
        String login        = args[1];
        String channel      = args[2];

        IRCClient client = new IRCClient(serverAddress, serverPort, nick, login, channel);
    } //end main

} //end class
```

Comment: What is confusing you about the error? `InputStreamReader` does not have a `readLine` method.

Comment: You have not shown us, but my presumption is that you have a class field defined as type `InputStreamReader`, since `reader` and `writer` are not available at the scope you are trying to use them. In such case, `BufferedReader reader = ` is a typo, since you are assigning to a local variable which is basically immediately discarded.

Comment: FWIW, any half decent IDE will warn you that these local variables are unused so I don't know how you missed it.

Comment: Edit your question with the updated details rather than posting to the comments

Comment: I edited the question with the remainder of the code.

Comment: @Michael every example I found online uses this method. What should I be using instead?

Comment: What do you mean "this method"? Unused local variable method? Find some better examples then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not initializing the fields, you are creating unused local variables, and your fields have the wrong type.

Change

```
private InputStreamReader reader    = null; //What we receive from the host
```

to

```
private BufferedReader reader;
```

And change

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
```

to

```
reader = new BufferedReader(
```

You will have similar problem with the writer. Do a similar thing for that.

Comment: Thank you! This fixed the problem. Not sure how I missed it.

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is, that the variables `reader` and `writer` are not visible in the while loop, but only within the try-catch-block they are declared in.

If you change your code like this it should at least compile (didn't test id because I don't have the server implementation):

```
//Client constructor
public IRCClient(String address, int port, String nick, String login, String channel) throws IOException {//EDITED HERE added throws declaration (either do this, or catch the exceptions)


//Client constructor
public IRCClient(String address, int port, String nick, String login, String channel) throws IOException {//EDITED HERE added throws declaration (either do this, or catch the exceptions)

    //Establish a connection to the host
    //EDITED HERE move the declaration here to have the variables visible
    BufferedWriter writer = null;
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    try {
        socket = new Socket(address, port);

        writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));

        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
    }
    catch (UnknownHostException u) {
        System.out.println(u);
    }
    catch (IOException i) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }

    //Login to the host
    try {
        writer.write("NICK " + nick + "\r\n");
        writer.write("USER " + login + "\r\n");
        writer.flush();
    }
    catch (IOException i) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }

    //Read lines from the server to make sure we are connected
    String line = null;
    try {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

            if (line.indexOf("004") >= 0) {
                // We are logged in
                break;
            }
            else if (line.indexOf("433") >= 0) {
                System.out.println("Nickname is already in use");
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (IOException i) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }

    // Join the specified channel
    writer.write("JOIN " + channel + "\r\n");
    writer.flush();

    // Keep reading lines from the host.
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {//EDITED HERE replaced read() with readLine()
        if (line.toLowerCase().startsWith("PING ")) {
            //Respond with PONG tro avoid being disconnected
            writer.write("PONG " + line.substring(5) + "\r\n");
            writer.flush();
        }
        else {
            //Print the line received
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    } //end while
}
```

I marked the parts that I changed with a comment `//EDITED HERE`

Comment: Thank you, I should have included the surrounding code, where I defined the private variables.